# Vertical Line in TikZ Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I create a vertical line at (0,0) that the graph below loops around?

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={rad(60)}{rad(30)}, trig format=rad, title=all in radians,]
    \addplot3+ [domain=0:4*pi,samples=19,samples y=0]
    ({sin(x)},
    {cos(x)},
    {2*x/(4*pi)});
    \node [fill=white,draw=black,anchor=center] at
    ({sin(pi/2)},{cos(pi/2)},1) {X};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addplot3 [domain=0:2] (0,0,x);` is one option...

Comment: `\draw (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 0,0,2);` is another.

Comment: You might want to use `(axis cs: {sin(pi/2)},{cos(pi/2)},1)` for the node, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.